# ModuleNotFoundError: struggling to with imports within an imported program

Tags: python

I have a program, program1.py, that has this structure:

```
Program
--program1.py
--__init__.py
--data\
----__init__.py
----helper_data.py
--classes\
----__init__.py
----helper_class.py
```

In helper_class.py, there is an import statement `from data.helper_data import *`. When I run program1, this works perfectly.

I have a second program, program2.py. I have put program1.py on my PYTHONPATH. In program2.py, I use `import program1`. It finds the program, but when running the imports from program1.py, I get the following error stemming from the classes.helper_class: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data.helper_data'`.

I think I vaguely understand what's going on, but I can't figure out the fix or the search terms to find the answer. I've tried changing the import in program1 to `from ..data.helper_data import *` and get an error saying I've tried a relative import beyond the parent-level package. I've also tried `from .data.helper_data import *` and get the same ModuleNotFoundError.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I think You have to import "sys" package.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('E:\ToDataScientist')    # this is where the "Program" folder exists
from Program.data.helper_data import aa  # "aa" is the class or function in helper_data
from Program.data.helper_data import *   # include all from helper_data
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is it, as when I print(sys.path), program1 is already there. The problem is the imports inside of program1.

Comment: Then you should remove it from PYTHON_PATH first. You don't need that, though. Just do as I told you. It'll work.

Comment: Then I'm unable to import it program2. I don't think I'm following you.

Comment: Where is program2.py? You didn't tell it.

Comment: It's a completely unrelated script. program1.py is useful in a number of places for me, so I want to be able to import it globally, but also run it by itself when needed. program1.py by itself works. In program2.py, `import program1` works. It is an import within program1.py that is throwing the error, but only when it is called as a module and not as a script.

Comment: I see. Then you can import program1.py like "from Program import program1", or "from Program.program1 import *"
If you import Program as I told you. You can import anything inside it.

Comment: I did try this and I'm getting the same error. Now it just says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Program'. I've tried both with Program's actual directory name and program1.py's name -- neither works.

Comment: Could you let me know the path? It should be the parent folder path of "Program" folder.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to respond. I think I figured it out. The problem is that both program1 and program2 had folders named "data" -- I think the interpreter was confused by this. Once I changed the folder name in program1 to something more unique (and updated every reference to it in the program), things started working. Thanks again for helping me through it! :)